# For Loop within separate ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to produce a database from a stream of information in excel (converted from a PDF file). After some help from here, the individual ranges which are required to be searched through have been defined and now I am attempting to scan through these individual ranges for specific triggers. The intention is then to extract data dependent on which of these triggers is present within the data.

I am currently trying to create a For Loop to scan through all the different ranges and extract the sought after information but am coming unstuck with the For Loop i think.

My data is in this following format (approximately 900 lines in total in excel)

```
Biodiesel  
Loss Number:  
88840  
Three people were killed and five injured in a fire that broke out in a biodiesel plant. People living eight km away reported hearing an explosion. A building collapsed on the victims of the incident.  
Event Date:  
22/11/2008  
Country:  
Turkey  
Location:  
Antakya, southern province of Hatay  
Event:  
Explosion, fire  
Cause:  
Explosion  
Plant Status:  
Operating  
Fatalities:  
3  
Injuries:    
5
```

The problem is that the data does not follow the same format so I would like to split into ranges based on the "Loss Number:" and then scan each of the ranges for approximately 10 possible headings. However, I am unsure how to scan through the individual ranges?

Any help would be appreciated.

My current code is;

```
Sub RangePrintTest()


Dim pd(100000, 100)
Dim rpd(10000, 100)
Dim VirtMat(300, 100)
Dim c As Integer
Dim npd As Variant


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Input Sheet")


Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dn As Range
Dim Temp As String
Dim k
Dim cc As Long


Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For Each Dn In Rng
If Not .Exists(Dn.Value & Dn.Offset(1).Value) And Dn.Value = "Loss Number:" Then
.Add Dn.Value & Dn.Offset(1).Value, Dn
Temp = Dn.Value & Dn.Offset(1).Value
Else
Set .Item(Temp) = Union(.Item(Temp), Dn)
End If
Next

Dim p
For Each k In .keys
    cc = cc + 1
    VirtMat(cc, 1) = .Item(k).Address
Next k
End With


End With


Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For i = 1 To 41
X = VirtMat(i, 1).Value
i = i + 1
Set TestRange = Range(X)
Do Until R = 21
If TestRange(R, 1) = "Loss Number:" Then
If TestRange(R + 1, 1) <> "" Then LossNumber = TestRange(R + 1, 1)

If TestRange(R, 1) <> "Loss Number:" Then LossNumber = NoInfo

cr = cr + 1

rpd(cr, 1) = LossNumber


End If

R = R + 1

Loop
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe you can describe what the actual problem is and produce a minimal SSCCE?

Comment: I hope this edit has maybe cleared it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
For i = 1 To 41
X = VirtMat(i, 1).Value
i = i + 1

// other stuff

Next
```

This kind of `For ... Next` loop automatically increments the loop variable  - `i` in this case - after each run through the loop. You are also manually incrementing `i` in your code so will miss out half of the entries in `VirtMat`. You will read entry 1, miss entry 2, read entry 3 and so on.

Try removing the `i = i + 1` line and see if that helps. More info on `For ... Next` loops is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601(v=office.15).aspx)